# How do I set the name of a window in ROR?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I "name" a browser window in ROR, such that I can open a page in it later, from another (popup) window (using the target="name" html parameter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use JavaScript for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.name = "MyWindow";
</script>
```

Of course you could easily package this up into a Rails helper method. For example, in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` add a new method:

```
def window_name(name)
  content_for(:window_name) do
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.name = \"#{name}\";</script>"
  end
end
```

Next, in your layout file, add this line somewhere within the HTML `<head>` element:

```
<%= yield :window_name %>
```

Finally, in your view templates, simply add a line like this (can be anywhere you want) to output the correct JavaScript:

```
<% window_name 'MyWindow' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try below:

```
var x=window.open("", "myWindow");
var y="<head><title>my window</title></head><body>my window</body>";
x.document.write(y);
```